# Is ‘noise level’ idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage

I think ‘noisiness level’ is exact and somewhat correct but I’ve noticed that ‘noise level’ is used more. However, I think sound (noise) has no levels, but loudness (noisiness) has levels. It seems like using ‘light level’ instead of ‘brightness level.’ Is ‘noise level’ just an idiom?

Comment: You imply that 'light level' is incorrect, but that isn't the case - try googling it.

Comment: So the light from a million Watt laser and a candle are the same? Good luck with your eyesight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remember that there is a difference between sound, and noise. 'Noise' is generally *negative* - unwanted sound. For example, we might speak of the *sound* of birdsong, but the *noise* of traffic

"Noise level" and "sound level" both seems perfectly idiomatic to me. But these words cannot be used alone to determine volume. You need terms like 'loud' or 'quiet' to define that; or to be more accurate, you would need to use a measurable scale like the number of decibels.

Something that is 'noisy' is producing any unwanted amount of noise, loud or relatively quiet. For example, a 'noisy jet engine' might be louder than a 'noisy eater'. For that reason, "noisiness" is not a term you could use interchangeably with 'noise level', because it simply means the state of being noisy and does not describe the volume level.

"Loudness" is a different matter, as it is a relative term. I have seen the word 'loudness' used as a technical term, ie a 'loudness control'. On audio hardware or software, 'loudness' might label the control for raising or lowering the volume.

Comment: In electronic circuits, 'noise level' is used to discuss the level of unwanted signal present along with the desired signal. It is impossible to eliminate, only to reduce.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That definition also applies to random variation over any large collection of data, whether that be snow on an old television, constant unpredictable fluctuations in values, etc.  In fact that's exactly what it means in relation to an audio signal - the wave graph of white noise (audio) looks very similar to that of cosmic radiation (which causes TV snow) or unwanted electrical signals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For something that is spread out across a space or volume, it's "level" is the amount of it per unit of that space or volume.

Water level:  amount of water per unit of area

Testosterone level:  amount of testosterone per unit of blood volume

Sound (pressure) level:  Amount of sound energy received per unit of receiving area

Noise level (colloquial): Sound pressure level of the noisy components of sound.  There are several other interpretations in engineering, over units of time or frequency.

Anxiety level (of a person): Amount of anxiety experienced per unit of time

Anxiety level (in a room): A metaphor that imagines anxiety to be like a quality of the air that affects everybody in the room.  It thereby has a 'level' like the concentration of a substance.

... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

"Noise level" is very idiomatic. Regular middle-class Americans say it all the time. Depending on context "noise" or "noisy" serve the same purpose. It sounds wrong to use "noisy level" or "noisiness level". Noise level is part of sounding-scientific wordplay. People say they have to "hydrate" instead of saying they want to drink something. Noise level is the same way -- just a fun substitute for noisy that might make you sound smarter.

About a coffeeshop someone might say "I can't take the noise level in that place". They might also say "that place is too noisy". A teacher might tell kids "keep down the noise", or "watch the noise level".

It's understood that "level" in "noise level" means a lot of noise. For example it sounds fine to say "the high noise level is giving me a headache", but it would be just as good to leave it out: "the noise level is...". Or in "what's the noise level like?" it's understood you're asking whether it's too noisy.